# ag-grid: Failed to instantiate module app

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, angular-fullstack

I'm adding ag-grid to an angular app created with angular-fullstack yeoman generator. it uses ES6, so i have to use "import" syntax in my app.js
i installed with npm:

npm install ag-grid --save

then added an import line in app.js as mentioned in the get-started:

import {Grid} from 'ag-grid/main';

then in i added the new "Grid" to my list of modules, like this

angular.module('app', [ngCookies, ngResource, ngSanitize, uiRouter, uiBootstrap, _Auth, account,
admin, navbar, footer, main, Grid
])

Then i get an error in my chrome console:

angular.js:68Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions, params) due to:
Error: [$injector:strictdi] Grid is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$i...di?p0=Grid
at http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:194:13
at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:4078:18)
at injectionArgs (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:4805:37)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:4836:19)

Does anybody know how to solve this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure that this will in fact help, try this:

```
var module = angular.module("app", ["agGrid",...the rest of your dependencies]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem here is that it is ES6 and the syntax is a bit different. first you import the package to any name you want, then you include it in your module declaration. my guess is the name is not important, it's like a var. what is important, is what we import. in the Getting Started the instruction is to import ag-grid/main. i also tried ag-grid, aggrid, all with no luck.  angular version is 1.5.8 . thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call

```
import {initialiseAgGridWithAngular1} from 'ag-grid/main';
initialiseAgGridWithAngular1();
```

Comment: should be in the same place as you put `import {Grid} from 'ag-grid/main';`